# Return a View for a separate MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two Visual Studio MVC Projects, each a different website.

I have one main site and have added a Reference to the other project.

How do I return a view from the other Website?

```
using Forum;
public ActionResult Forum()
{
// ??? How to add a view from the Forum ???
return View();
}
```

My forum is MVCForum: http://www.mvcforum.com/

Thanks you.

Comment: Ideally, you want to make REST call, and return JSON. Btw, I did not downvote your question.

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator.  There are many people using that package to reference views in one project from another.